# Select2 posting values that have been entered

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in my asp.net mvc website and have got it working for html `<select>`. However I am finding it difficult to get a way of retrieving the values a user has entered when they hit submit.  Once inside a @using (Html.BeginForm) element the select2 no longer works and just shows as the default. I've tried this tutorial but it's not working for me: http://www.datahaunting.com/mvc/select2-simple-example-in-asp-net-mvc/

Here is what I have at the minute and what I have tried:

```
@model AssignerWebTool.Models.CreateUserModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
}
<select id="select" class="select" multiple="multiple"> //This works but I have no way of getting the values entered
<option></option>
</select>

<h2>Create User</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "select", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr/>
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {id = "select" }) //This does not work and does not select2

        <select id="select" class="select" multiple="multiple"> //Also does not work now inside of here
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create User"/>
    </div>
</div>


}

@section scripts
{
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#select").select2({
            placeholder: "Email address(es)",
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: When you try the code above, do you get rid of the select attempts other than the one you are trying at the time?  You have 3 elements with id="select" and the jquery to run select2 will only work on the first one it finds.  Please try again by commenting out the select that is first and see if then the next one works.

Comment: That does solve one of the issue I was having and makes sense.  I still cant get it to work for the @Html.TextBoxFor element though, even when I just use the id="select" on it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to duplicate, and I realize that I'm not sure what issue you are having with the TextBoxFor is.  The only issue I ran into was resolved when I used the Full js lib: select2.full.min.js - not sure if you want to try that.  What is the issue, is it silently failing on you without rendering the jquery control or is there an error?

Comment: Yeah tried that and its at least changing into a select2 box.  The problem im now encountering is that its just using the default select 2, with tags and token separators not working, the placeholder is working though.  Might they not be supported on a textboxfor?  Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments we adjusted the following:

-Only have 1 element with the id="select" that is being selected via JQuery to enable the Select2 functionality for.

-Use the select2.full.js lib for v4.0.x for full backward compatibility from v3.5.x

It appears that for an `<input type="text">` (generated via @Html.TextBoxFor() in the question code sample) field to be used in Select2 v4.0.x that there are limitations (https://github.com/select2/select2/releases lists 'Limited support' for v4.0.0 RC1), which include tags and token separators not working.

Instead of using the html helper generated input field - use a select field, since that is recommended to use with Select2 (see release notes for v4.0.0), and make sure this is inside the form and has the name attribute set to the Model's property, and if you want to load in the values passed by the Controller via the model then loop through those as well:

```
<select id ="select" name="Email" class="select" multiple="multiple">
    @{foreach (var item in Model.Email)
        {
            <option>@item </option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Also, if Email is just a string, it will only get the first selected item from the select element when the form is submitted (if relying on Model binding at least), to get more you can make the property an `IEnumerable<string>` or a SelectList, and at that point you could go back to using the html helper but with a DropDownFor to get the select element generated (though you don't need to, the generated html is basically identical to above).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Email, Model.Email, new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

and you can also call Select2 directly on the auto generated id:

```
$("#Email").select2({
```

and handling the posted form in your userController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserModel model)
{
  ...
```

via Model Binding, which isn't the only way but I would recommend.

Hope this all helps!

Comment: See im not worried so much about actually passing in values for a drop down, I was more looking for values to be tokenised as they were entered as in this example: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tokenizer  It seems this might not be possible though unless I am missing something?

Comment: If I use the <select> is there a way for me to pass the entered values when the form is submitted?

Comment: Figured it out, can get the data from the ,select. element using a Request.Form["Email"].  Thanks you've been a great help to me.